# How to log into file with log4j without Spring and hibernate logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to use log4j library to log stuff in my application.
I'm initializing it without xml (through java code).
There is code:

```
public static void initLogger() {
        try {
          String filePath = "mylog.log";
          PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%-5p %d %m%n");
          RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender(layout, filePath);
          appender.setName("myFirstLog");
          appender.setMaxFileSize("1MB");
          appender.activateOptions();
          Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When i want to log something in my class I use this:

```
public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);
```

Everything working fine, but the logger appends file spring and hibernate logs. How i log info into the file without spring and hibernate logs? Do i need to create a new instance of log4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender);
```

try

```
Logger.getLogger("myrootpackage").addAppender(appender);
```

e.g.

```
Logger.getLogger("com.mycompany").addAppender(appender);
```